# Firebase Rules Wildcard and Child comparison

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time, wildcard, firebase-security

I'm trying to mix Firebase's Rule wildcards with children comparisons.

I'm reading a child elsewhere who's value is '4'.

When I do a literal comparison, the simulator gives me the green light (like this):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "die": {
      "rolls": {
        "$i": {
          ".read": "4 == root.child('die/i').val()"
        }
      },
      "i": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output (success):

```
Type    read
Location    /die/rolls/4
Data    null
Auth    null
Read successful
Line 7 (/die/rolls/4)
read: "4 == root.child('die/i').val()"
```

But a wildcard comparison fails. Why?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "die": {
      "rolls": {
        "$i": {
          ".read": "$i == root.child('die/i').val()"
        }
      },
      "i": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output (failure):

```
Type    read
Location    /die/rolls/4
Data    null
Auth    null
Read denied
Line 7 (/die/rolls/4)
read: "$i == root.child('die/i').val()"
```

(also, I've tried simulating authentication; same thing.)

Comment: Converted it into text and gave what errors/logs I could. Thanks

Comment: Appreciated! ( I can't help with your actual question, but wishing you good luck for that )

Comment: Alex, if @Padawan answer is ok you really should select it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because

```
root.child('die/i').val()
```

returns a number. Per the firebase documentation

> Note: Path keys are always strings. For this reason, it's important to keep in mind that when we attempt to compare a $ variable to a number, this will always fail. This can be corrected by converting the number to a string (e.g. $key === newData.val()+'')

The following gives you your desired results

```
 {
 "rules": {
   "die": {
     "rolls": {
       "$i": {
         ".read": "$i === root.child('die/i').val()+''"
       }
     },
     "i": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": true
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data)